# Unable to Read a tsv file in pandas. Gives UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 113: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a tsv file (one of many) but it is given me the following error.

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 113: invalid start byte`

Before this I have read similar other files using the same code.

`df = pd.read_csv(fname,sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False)`

But for this particular, I am getting an error.

How can I read this file? Hopefully without missing any data.

Comment: It would help to see an example of your data - could you add some example data to your question that replicates your error?

Comment: @bm13563, how/where can I upload the data file?

Comment: @AlhpaDelta Your could simply post a few rows of the data you are trying to read. You probably can open it as txt, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion would be to check waht encoding you actually have. Do it this way:

```
with open('filename.tsv) as f:  ### or whatever your etension is
   print(f)
```

from that you'll obtain the encoding. Then,

df=pd.read_csv('filename.tsv', encoding="the encoding that was returned")

It would be nice if you could post lien 113 of you dataset, where the first occurrence of the error occured.

Comment: it said encoding='cp1252'. Wonder what the difference is that causes it to blow up. and is there a way to factor in different encodings without having to check specifically.